# can の as "'s" be used with verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-の

This is actually more than one question but they are connected, I dont know how to post them separated and make sense.

I was reading a translation of ゆめの続きはどこだ!? as "Where Does the Dream Continue?!

Now I knew one of the use of の is similar to the "'s" of english. But the "'s" is used only with nouns and here it's used to connect a noun with a verb. is here the verb used as a noun and a more literal translation would be "where does the dream's continuation is?" and the translation was adapted to sound more natural? (correct me if I'm wrong) . And the other question is, when I want to join a noun with a verb with the の particle, do I have to put the verb in infinitive?

Comment: The translation has been arranged, literally it renders as "where is the dream's sequel?" as you guessed, here 続き is a noun not a verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right!

[続き｛つづき｝](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8D&ref=sa) here is a noun form of the verb 続く｛つづく｝meaning "continuation" or "sequel".

ゆめの続き - The dream's continuation

ゆめの続きはどこだ - The dream's continuation is where? (literal translation)

==> Correct for fluency:  "Where Does the Dream Continue?!" <-- your translation :)

---

As for verb --> noun changes, it works for some verbs, but not all. Here are some examples

違う｛ちがう｝ To differ, disagree --> 違い Difference

答える｛こたえる｝To answer --> 答え (an) Answer

悲しむ｛かなしむ｝To be sad --> 悲しみ Sadness

But this doesn't apply to all cases like,

食べる　to eat ->　食べ (an eat?)

数える to count - > 数え (a count?)

In these cases, it all depends on the word, some of these words just use their kanjis for the noun form. (食 as in 日本食、数 as in 点数 etc.)